# Change method signature with @Aspect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, aspect

Can you change a method's signature in Spring using aspects?

Like effectively transform the following:

```java
@GetMapping("/thing")
@User // custom annotation that should authenticate the user
public ResponseEntity getThing() {
    ... // user is successfully authenticated, get the "thing" from the database
}
```

into:

```java
@GetMapping("/thing")
public ResponseEntity getThing(@CookieValue("Session-Token") String sessionToken) {
    User user = authenticator.authenticateSessionTokenOrThrow(sessionToken);
    ... // user is successfully authenticated, get the "thing" from the database
}
```

With the `user` variable also becoming available for use in the method body.

If not, how can I achieve the same result without repeating the code (parameter and authenticator call) everywhere?

Comment: Let me know if you need other clarifications. I like bytecode/source manipulation topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspects aren't meant for that.

Yes, they can effectively modify `.class` files bytecode, with compile time or run time weaving, but they **do not** override methods' signatures.

Also, the default Spring AOP Aspects are implemented in pure Java, and thus cannot touch the bytecode layer. For that you'd need AspectJ.

Tools for customizing bytecode at run/compile time are [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/), [ByteBuddy](https://bytebuddy.net/#/), CGLIB or Javassist.

---

**However**, you can probably accomplish this via an [Annotation Processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html), which lets you modify the actual *sources*, instead of the already compiled bytecode.

---

> If not, how can I achieve the same result without repeating the code
>   (parameter and authenticator call) everywhere?

Possible solutions are

1. [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html), which simply throws an `Exception` if the user isn't authenticated
2. Standard Spring AOP advice, which simply throws an `Exception` if the user isn't authenticated
3. Spring Security

1 is pretty easy.
2 is more time-consuming
3 imho, seems the best match for authentication, but it's the most complex, probably

---

> The HandlerInterceptor can choose which methods it applies to?

No, unfortunately. I had a requirement a couple of months ago to "cover" only certain methods with an `Interceptor`, and I implemented a custom solution, which simply look for an annotation specified on the method itself.

This is an extract of my custom `HandlerInterceptor`, which looks for the `CheckInit` annotation, first on the type, and then on the method, for a more specific customization.

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response,
        final Object handler
) throws Exception {
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
        if (shouldCheckInit((HandlerMethod) handler)) {
            checkInit();
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static boolean shouldCheckInit(final HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
    final var typeAnnotation = handlerMethod.getBeanType().getAnnotation(CheckInit.class);
    final var shouldCheckInit = typeAnnotation != null && typeAnnotation.value();

    final var methodAnnotation = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(CheckInit.class);
    return (methodAnnotation == null || methodAnnotation.value()) && shouldCheckInit;
}

private void checkInit() throws Exception {
    if (!manager.isActive()) {
        throw new NotInitializedException();
    }
}
```

> The "Standard Spring AOP advice" seems interesting, do you have a link
>   for that?

[Spring AOP documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop) - look for the Java-based configuration (I hate XML)

> AspectJ really touches the bytecode and can modify signatures as well?

You could make AspectJ modify signatures. Just fork the project and modify its Java Agent or compiler.

> AFAIK Annotation Processors cannot modify classes, they can only
>   create new ones.

The thing is, they don't modify `.class` files, instead they modify source files, which means they simply edit them. E.g. Lombok uses annotation processing to modify source files.

But yes, the modified sources are written to a new file.

Comment: **1.** The `HandlerInterceptor` can choose which methods it applies to? (Not all methods need authentication + there are different types of users.) **2.** The "Standard Spring AOP advice" seems interesting, do you have a link for that? **3.** Might look into Spring Security in the future, but for now it is too much rework. **4.** AFAIK Annotation Processors cannot *modify* classes, they can only create new ones. **5.** AspectJ really touches the bytecode and can modify signatures as well?

Comment: Thanks! **1.** Isn't checking the annotations in run-time adding massive overhead? **2.** According to Baeldung `...The notable exception is the Lombok library which uses annotation processing as a bootstrapping mechanism to include itself into the compilation process and modify the AST via some internal compiler APIs. This hacky technique has nothing to do with the intended purpose of annotation processing...`: https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder

Comment: @anddero nah, don't even think about optimizing this part of your codebase. Bottlenecks are not here. Spring uses annotations everywhere and inside the `HandlerInterceptor` you're really deep on the call stack, so optimizing would have minimal impact (the heavy job has already been done by Spring). Though, what I did add on top of the `shouldCheckInit` was a Guava Cache, to cache the {`HandlerMethod`s - doCheck} association. But that means adding another layer of complexity.

For Lombok, you're right, it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: @anddero ah by the way, Reflection is no more *that* heavy. Getting an annotation is by no means a big deal.